# MS Access attachment

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

may you consult a little bit? In a database a client likes to store a PDF as an attachment within each record. The file size is around 1Mb. We are talking about 5000 - 10000 records. MS Access (2007) is limited to 2Gb per database. However I see another, earlier problem using an application like this: the performance. Is there anybody with some experience? I just learned to link to these binary datas and store the files on a fileserver.

Thank you for any advice!
Regards Urs

Comment: Yes, an Access database file is limited to 2GB so what you've described will almost certainly not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I've always stored the file on a file server, and I store the file path in a field of the record. That's always worked well for me.

Comment: Michael, that is the way I always used. I am convinced that not the size of the db will be the problem but the performance of access itself. So before we are going to arrive the max size of 2GB we will bury the db because of too long response time.

Comment: The problem will be both but given that 5000 x 1Mb = 5GB it just can't work whatever the performance is like.